# Good way to style padding of nested uls that should appear at the same level

Tags: html, css

I have [this type of structure](http://dabblet.com/gist/2996385)

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>
        two has children
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        three has children
        <ul>
            <li>x</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Although logically everything is organized like this I need to display everything in a single flat-looking list.

I can do that by removing margins and padding from ul,li but that litterally makes it so that no li can have padding.

I would like to pad **all** list items by 5px but simply doing that will actually indent the nested li's by 10px on the left and on top.  [Basically I need it to look like this](http://dabblet.com/gist/2996510). What's a good way of setting up padding that *won't* push over the nested lists.

I am free to modify the basic html structure but I would like to keep the nesting as it makes a lot of other stuff that I'm doing easier (such as expandable/hideable children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is select only the topmost `<ul>`, and then give only its child (but not grandchild) `<li>` elements spacing using the CSS > selector.

For example, specifying the topmost element with an id:

HTML:

```
<ul id="Head">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>
        two has children
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        three has children
        <ul>
            <li>x</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#Head > li
{
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

And [here's the example](http://jsfiddle.net/Mgdwr/) on jsFiddle.

Comment: That will only give padding to the top level of `li`s I need padding on all the lis but *the same amount of padding* on all of them (so it shouldn't build up with nesting)

Comment: The lower level `<li>`s will inherit their parent's padding but won't have any padding of their own, which leads to them all displaying as if they had 5 px padding. Just try it and see if it gives the result you want, or look at the jsFiddle.

Comment: This will work for `padding-left` but not for other types of padding See here: http://jsfiddle.net/m5E5K/ however getting a bit more specific DOES solve the issue http://jsfiddle.net/m5E5K/1/ so thanks

Comment: Seems like to get exactly what I want I have to add one more element denoting what the "content" is: http://jsfiddle.net/m5E5K/2/

Comment: One more thing - not a good idea to use jsfiddle for this sort of thing since it looks like they include a reset css.

Answer (score 2):

This css:

```
li {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

li li {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

should handle arbitrarily deep nested lists. I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WwQx/3/) as an example. (The example uses paddings of 15px to make it more obvious.)

Comment: Whoops. Fixed. I had two examples, one with padding and one with margin but I then noticed the OP specified padding... Thanks.