# Select ul li child not grandchildren

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, children

I found a CSS selector to select a child li and not grandchild li from the parent ul:

```
parentulid > li
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210657/good-way-to-style-padding-of-nested-uls-that-should-appear-at-the-same-level)

But how to select the same from a top parent div, nested like this?

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="Head">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>
            two has children
            <ul>
                <li>a</li>
                <li>b</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            three has children
            <ul>
                <li>x</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this doesn't work :

```
#header > ul li {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

because grandchildren li are affected too.

Answer (score 6):

Use `>` again, like `#header > ul > li`. This will only match `li`s that are direct descendants of `ul`s that are direct descendants of `#header`.

Comment: Perfect! You sent good answer before I had time to edit error in my post

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the child selector again like so:

```
#header > ul > li{
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

This selects all `li` elements that are an immediate child of any `ul` element that is itself an immediate child of `#header`.  Your previous selector `#header > ul li` selects all `li` descendants (including in nested `uls`) of any `ul` that is an immediate child of `#header`.

Basically, `#header > ul li` would select ANY `li` that is a descendant node in the DOM of any `ul` that is a direct descendant (child) of `#header`, even if it is nested in 1 or 2 or 10 more sublists.  By contrast `#header > ul > li` ONLY selects immediate descendant `li` elements of immediate descendant `ul` elements from `#header`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean somthing like this ?

```
#header > ul > li > ul li{
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wVMb8/